# IE8 not working with CSS3 animation, what jQuery alternative is there?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, css-transitions

I understand that ie8 is not compatible with a lot that css3 has.  For this animation is there a work around to still have the animation work in ie8? Such as an extra snippet of jQuery?

http://webapps.easy2.com/ce/ext1104/messages/iris_messages.html

Answer (score 2):

You can very well use jQuery's [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method.

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {
  $('#book').animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: '+=50',
    height: 'toggle'
  }, 5000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```